# Delete a symlink

Tags: macos, file, symlink

I tried to uninstall an application (Tunnelblick) on MacOSX 10.8.4 (Mountain Lion) but I can't empty the trash.
If I look in the application folder, I found a single file that is the problem.
So I tried to delete it via Terminal but the following errors occur:

```
> file Headers
Headers: broken symbolic link to Versions/Current/Headers

> rm Headers
rm: Headers: No such file or directory

> unlink Headers
unlink: Headers: No such file or directory
```

Do you understand where is the problem ?

edit: I tried to relink the symlink to an empty file, now I have:

```
> file Headers
Headers: empty

> rm Headers
rm: Headers: Operation not permitted

> unlink Headers
unlink: Headers: Operation not permitted
```

I tried too:

```
> chflags noschg Headers

> rm Headers
rm: Headers: Operation not permitted
```

Please, need help to understand why I can't delete it.

Comment: You shouldn't need `sudo`. What happens when you `rm` without it?

Comment: Same response: No such file or directory

Answer (score 3):

You might need to determine where the symlink points to : `readlink -v Headers`

Then, you could link it again : `ln -sfn foo.bar Headers` where `foo.bar` is the pointed file.

Or delete the pointed file, and then delete the symlink, using `rm -rf` for both.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I relinked the symlink to an empty file. Redirection is OK but now, rm -rf Headers return "Operation not permitted". Note: when I move .app file package to the trash (in/out), administrator password is required.

Comment: It may be a matter of rights. have you tried `sudo rm -rf` ?

Comment: Yes I did, i tried multiple combinations but alays the same error: "Operation not permitted" (thank you again for your help!)

Comment: Try to change the permissions by right-clicking the file, choosing `Get info`, then `Ownership & Permissions`. Make the file become readable and writable for your user, and try again the `rm -rf` command.

Comment: I checked permissions too. My own user have read and write permissions  for this folder, I feel it is system registered application and is protected by a flag but my ability stops here... The application is used to connect to a VPN server and redirect all data traffic.

Comment: Note: The application is not running

Comment: You may need to use `chflags` with the `-RL` options, like this : 
`sudo chflags -RL nouchg Headers`. So you can change the flags of the file hierarchy rooted in the file. This is my last piece of advice, hope it works :)

Comment: Thank you again for your help but this command line had no effect, this symlink stays undeletable. I will try to contact editor if they can help me. Thank you again!